# Add upper bound to colour bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, colorbar

I'm trying to show enrichment pvals in my dataset. I want to create a heatmap like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax = sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(enrichment_per_decile))
ax.set_title("negative log pval (poisson)")
```

[image: heatmap with inadequate colorbar]

However, due to the extreme values in the upper centre of the figure, I lose out on granularity in the other sections, despite the pval being very significant.

I was following this tutorial on how to customise your colorbar, but I can only seem to get the colorbar to replace the figure, and not be added next to it.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax = sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(enrichment_per_decile))
ax.set_title("negative log pval (poisson)")
fig.colorbar(
    mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="magma"),
    cax=ax,
    extend="max")
```

[image: colorbar replaces heatmap :(]

How can I add an upper bound to the colorbar, so that all values above 200 are the same colour, leaving more space for the rest of the figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vmax` parameter.

```
ax = sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(enrichment_per_decile), vmax = 200)
```

Comment: That works for the actual heatmap, thanks! You wouldn't know how to change the colorbar as I described as well?

Comment: Hmm.. not sure if I understand what you want. Maybe providing a minimal reproducible input data and the expected plot would help.